# Facelet parsing or what is occuring when tag <h:inputText id="text"/> is parsing

Tags: java, xml, jsf, xhtml

I have a simple web application which contains facelet `index.xhtml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
      <body> <h:inputText id="text"/> </body>
</html>
```

I'm interested what's occuring in detail when compiler parse `<h:inputText id=text"/>`. I hope it help me to realize `JSF`. I assume that the sequnce of actions is:

1. Compiler going to namespace by the `xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"` and trying to find tag inputText in this case.
2. If tag is founded compiler run tag handler which defines by FOR EXAMPLE `<handler-class>com.example.SomeHandler</handler-class>` inside the tag `<tag></tag>`.
3. By the tag hadler compiler found `UIComponent` class and renderer class, corresponding to this tag.

I think, that i have wrong understand of parsing process, because renderer class registered to `component family`... Please explain me the correct action sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a lot closer to the answer than you know. Facelets uses taglibs similarly to JSP, these are declared in a .taglib.xml file that looks similar to this

```
<facelet-taglib>
  <namespace>http://www.mycompany.com/jsf</namespace>
  <tag>
    <tag-name>bar</tag-name>
    <component>
      <component-type>javax.faces.Data</component-type>
      <renderer-type>com.mycompany.Bar</renderer-type>
    </component>
  </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

The namespace element in the taglib file references the URL you will use in your facelets documents (in the xmlns attributes) to reference this taglib, meanwhile the individual tag elements define the individual tags in the taglib.

In the case of the above taglib, you would use the 'bar' tag that was defined like so

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:m="http://www.mycompany.com/jsf">
    <body><m:bar/></body>
</html>
```

By doing this, facelets will look up the taglib associated with the namespace "http://www.mycompany.com/jsf", find the tag definition for 'bar' and then use the discovered UIComponent in the  definition to render the desired output for the tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have a some doubts. For what we declare `componentFamily` varible if we explicit show that our renderer will be registered to `javax.faces.Data` component type? I dont understand the sense.

Comment: It it true that the `javax.faces.Data` component type will be founded in component family which declared with annotation `@FacesRenderer`?